# Слои в html один рисунок на другой

Tags: html

У меня проблема мне нужно сделать чтобы одна картинка была внизу а другая как бы поверх его. Но получается все наоборот знает кто нибудь как исправить?
Помогите буду благодарна

Comment: Добавьте Вашу разметку и css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Картинке, которая должна быть ниже, присвойте css z-index:0, а той, что выше - z-index 1 (или больше)
Пример:

```
<img src='url' style='z-index:0;'> <!-- эта будет ниже -->
<img src='url' style='z-index:99;'> <!-- эта будет выше -->
```